# Python equivalent from a very simple Java program example

Tags: java, python, oop

I'm currently reading the official Java tutorial and I'd like to compare an example of code given to its equivalent in Python. Could someone please give me the equivalent Python code for the following Java code :

```
class Bicycle {

   int cadence = 0;
   int speed = 0;
   int gear = 1;

   void changeCadence(int newValue) {
        cadence = newValue;
   }

   void changeGear(int newValue) {
        gear = newValue;
   }

   void speedUp(int increment) {
        speed = speed + increment;   
   }

   void applyBrakes(int decrement) {
        speed = speed - decrement;
   }

   void printStates() {
        System.out.println("cadence:"+cadence+" speed:"+speed+" gear:"+gear);
   }
```

}

and the objects instantiated from this class :

```
class BicycleDemo {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

      // Create two different Bicycle objects
      Bicycle bike1 = new Bicycle();
      Bicycle bike2 = new Bicycle();

      // Invoke methods on those objects
      bike1.changeCadence(50);
      bike1.speedUp(10);
      bike1.changeGear(2);
      bike1.printStates();

      bike2.changeCadence(50);
      bike2.speedUp(10);
      bike2.changeGear(2);
      bike2.changeCadence(40);
      bike2.speedUp(10);
      bike2.changeGear(3);
      bike2.printStates();
 }
```

}

Thanks,

Bruno

Comment: Please attempt your own Python translation.  Post **your** Python and we'll comment on it.  We're not really happy doing your homework for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be :

```
class Bicycle:

    def __init__(self):
        self.cadence = 0
        self.speed  = 0 
        self.gear  =1




    def changeCadence(self, newValue):
        self.cadence = newValue


    def changeGear(self, newValue):
        self.gear = newValue


    # and same for other functions



if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = Bicycle()
    obj.changeCadence()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for not posting my attempt. I'm reading currently a Python tutorial and I wonder : we don't have to put class Bicycle(object) ?

Comment: In Python you usually don't write getters and setters.  They are a bit pointless since Python supports descriptors.

Comment: You missed a colon on your `class Bicycle`, just so ya know.

Answer (score 1):

[Relevant Information located at docs.python.org](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html)

Answer (score 0):

On the off-chance this isn't homework:

```
class Bicycle(object):
    def __init__(self, cadence=0, speed=0, gear=1, gearLabels=('A','B','C','D','E')):
        super(Bicycle,self).__init__()
        self.cadence    = cadence
        self.speed      = speed
        self.gearLabels = gearLabels
        self._gear      = None
        self.gear       = gear

    def speedUp(self, increment):
        self.speed += increment

    def applyBrakes(self, decrement):
        self.speed -= decrement

    @property
    def gear(self):
        return self.gearLabels[self._gear-1]

    @gear.setter
    def gear(self, gear):
        try:
            self._gear = self.gearLabels.index(gear) + 1
        except ValueError:
            if 0 < gear <= len(self.gearLabels):
                self._gear = gear
            else:
                raise ValueError("don't have gear {0}".format(gear))

    def incGear(self):
        self.gear = self._gear+1

    def decGear(self):
        self.gear = self._gear-1

    def __str__(self):
        return "cadence: {0}, speed: {1}, gear: {2}".format(self.cadence, self.speed, self.gear)

def main():
    bike1 = Bicycle()
    bike1.cadence = 50
    bike1.speedUp(10)
    bike1.gear = 2
    print(bike1)

    bike2 = Bicycle()
    bike2.cadence = 50
    bike2.speedUp(10)
    bike2.gear = 2
    bike2.cadence = 40
    bike2.speedUp(10)
    bike2.incGear()
    print(bike2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Note:

1. I have given the constructor default values so if you want to create a Bicycle(gear=3) you can.
2. Cadence and speed are accessed directly.
3. To show how to use property getters and setters, I have made gear accessible as a short set of labels and a private state property _gear which stores the current index.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually this isn't homework. I was preparing myself for a job interview and was really short on time. :-)

Answer (score -5):

More complete and more correct code - object is important since it change class model - contructor in this case is not since not input parameters - python have faster initialization in this case.

Have a fun ...

```
class Bicycle(object):
  cadence = 0
  speed = 0
  gear = 1

  def changeCadence(self, newValue):
    self.cadence = newValue

  def changeGear(self, newValue):
    self.gear = newValue

  def speedUp(self, increment):
    speed += increament

  def applyBrakes(self, descrement):
    speed -= decreament

  def printStates(self):
    print 'cadence: %s speed: %s gear: %s' % (self.cadence, self.speed, self.gear)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  # Create two different Bicycle objects
  bike1 = Bicycle()
  bike2 = Bicycle()

  # Invoke methods on those objects
  bike1.changeCadence(50)
  bike1.speedUp(10)
  bike1.changeGear(2)
  bike1.printStates()

  bike2.changeCadence(50)
  bike2.speedUp(10)
  bike2.changeGear(2)
  bike2.changeCadence(40)
  bike2.speedUp(10)
  bike2.changeGear(3)
  bike2.printStates()
```

Comment: -1 because outside of the constructor the parameters are class members and not instance members

Comment: This won't actually work anyway since the parameter names != the names used in functions.

Comment: I think you are to lazy to fix two o 3 letters and not really be programmers since can not solve such simple problem :)